# Clearing inline-blocks?

Tags: html, css

I have

```
.centered-holder {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then

```
<div class="centered-holder">misc content 1</div>
<div class="centered-holder">misc content 2</div>
<div class="centered-holder">misc content 3</div>
```

I only want one max per line, is this actually possible somehow? It's an iPhone HTML5 app so older browser restrictions aren't an issue.

Comment: The `clear` property will only affect floated elements, you have nothing floated.

Comment: actually clear doesn't need to be applied to a floated element, you can apply it to an inline element to stop it popping up. i need some comparable solution

Comment: No it doesn't need to be applied to a *floated* element, but it only clears *floated* elements. It will not 'clear' an inline-block element because it is not 'floating' on the left or right side. If you want them on separate lines, the solution below should work. Perhaps you could provide a better example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - setting them to display as block-level elements would fix this problem, and they'd remain centered, according to one of your comments. Why do you need them to be `inline-block`s?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Depend of your CSS declarations and your markup, but you can try to put this CSS declaration on the parent container:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

With this approach you avoid to transform the `.centered-holder` to a block element, and you can still use for example the `text-align:center` on the parent container.

---

> **pre-line**
>   - This value will cause sequences of whitespace to collapse into a single space character. Line breaks will occur wherever
>   necessary to fill line boxes, and at new lines in the markup (or at
>   occurrences of "\a" in generated content). In other words, it’s like
>   normal except that it’ll honor explicit line breaks.

You can find more informations here about white-space:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space

---

To finish, you can use these CSS declarations :

```
.parent-container {
    white-space: pre-line /* Create new line for each DIV */;
    line-height:0 /* Mask the extra lines */;
    *white-space: pre /*FixIE7*/;
    *word-wrap: break-word /*FixIE7*/;
}

.centered-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:100% /* Restore a default line-height */;
    *display: inline /*FixIE7*/;
    *zoom: 1 /*FixIE7*/;
}
```

I found this question very interesting, so I give also the CSS declarations for IE6-7 (`pre-line` and `inline-block` fixes). It should be usefull for some other people which have a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks great answer: ) Found out you can also have just blocks in your main content strip, then whack a text-align:center; on them. Then put the inline-blocks inside. By doing this your content is centered (because the parent block spans full width, and centers the inline-block inside)

Answer (score 6):

Changing `display:inline-block` to `display:table` may do the trick.

By default, a table clears it's sibling elements (like a block div), and it's width expands to fit it's content (like an inline div).

Comment: Used this to break a series of links to their own line on a media query. Was using :after and :before psuedo-elements for styling and the hover state. This worked as if "display: block;" but didn't fudge my psuedo-elements or hover.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove `display: inline-block;` they will stack one on top of the other.

Block-level elements begin on a new line, and a DIV is block-level by default.

Comment: yea i know that. the thing is I've got text-align:center on my container cause i like the auto centering ability, looks like I might have to do this with JS

Comment: You could always add:

.centered-holder:after{
    content:"\A";
}

Seems like a hack though.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just add a single div with display block after the inline-blocks.

```
.centered-holder {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.clear-inline {
    display: block;
}
```

Then

```
<div class="centered-holder">misc content 1</div>
<div class="clear-inline"></div>
<div class="centered-holder">misc content 2</div>
<div class="clear-inline"></div>
<div class="centered-holder">misc content 3</div>
<div class="clear-inline"></div>
```

Comment: That's really bad practice and very hacky.

Comment: Well, this IS CSS. Hacky is it's second name.

Comment: This can also be accomplished with pseudoelements, making it a little less hacky. See http://codepen.io/ivancamilov/pen/jqmWEL

Comment: You might as well just use a `<br>` tag if you want to add to the DOM.