# how to wrap heading (say <h1>) around borders ,only text area and continuous headings should remain in different line?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
    h1{
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: pink;
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

i have used inline-block to wrap the text around the heading, but the headings which i gave after first heading aligns themselves in a single line

(detailed description of problem)

```
<body>
    <h1>about me</h1>
    <h2>about me</h2>
    <h1>about me</h1>
</body>
```

result i am getting is :
about me(enclosed in border) about me(enclosed as well) about me(also enclosed) one the same line or horizontally

required is 
about me (enclosed within border)
about me (enclosed within border)
about me (enclosed within border)
on different line

please tell me it there is any property or way in CSS to do that?

P.S - i know the question is bit ambiguous but i have tried my best to explain.

Comment: result i am getting is : about me(enclosed in border) about me(enclosed as well) about me(also enclosed) "one (typing error its "on")" the same line or horizontally --- its not "one" its "on" sorry typing error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearing inline-blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177140/clearing-inline-blocks)

Comment: Can you show the output you want, any image?

Comment: @Atul OP wants inline-block to be treated like block to create a new line, but at the same time be inline-block where the border doesn't go all the way across the screen, just wraps the content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you applying the `display: inline-block;` on H1
As per the discussion in the comments above, as per my understanding, you need this.
Try the display flex, Wrap your items in a div or section and do it like this.
if you need something else, pls let me know.

```css
section > * {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: pink;
    border-style: solid;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>about me</h1>
  <h2>about me</h2>
  <h1>about me</h1>
</section>
```